# After making a Gradle groovy jar library how to make it re-usable for multiple local projects?

Tags: gradle, groovy, dependencies, shared-libraries

[Here](https://guides.gradle.org/building-groovy-libraries/) I read about how to make a Groovy library .jar ... i.e. pretty much the same as making a Groovy (standalone) project.  But I'm not clear what you do then with the resultant .jar...

Say I have two Eclipse "proper"/"standalone" projects (I'm using Groovy for everything) and I want them to share a third Gradle library project of mine as a dependency, which is merely a library of classes... how are my standalone projects expected to find the latest .jar version of the library which they're both using...?

My expectation would be that somehow these versions of the library .jar would have to under `GRADLE_USER_HOME` (i.e. same location as all other dependency .jars).

Then I would assume that in the build.gradle of both standalone projects you'd have a line like

```
compile 'mylibrary:mylibrarymodule:3.+'
```

... of course the first part of these compile directives normally involves a "domain name in reverse" ... and this is normally used by a repository like Maven.  How does it work with something which doesn't need to be published?

NB at the time of writing I don't have a Maven account as such and have no idea whether "publication" for re-use of a local common library project like this is essential or not.

Naturally, when I distribute versions of my standalone projects they will need to be packaged up with the library .jar in question.

A link to a how-to for a case like this would be more than welcome: I haven't found it under gradle.org.

Comment: You need to publish to somewhere. If it's just for you, you can publish to a directory on your machine, if it's for other people in your company to use, you may have a company repository you can publish to, if it's for everyone then bintray or maven (you can set bintray to publish to maven as well) https://newfivefour.com/gradle-bintray-tutorial.html

Comment: Or an alternative to pushing locally would be to use a composite build pattern to include this gradle build in other builds https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

Comment: Wow... vote to **close**...!  As though I'd asked simply the most preposterously, embarrassingly obvious thing in the world.  So obvious that there's no point in even leaving the briefest of remarks in a comment.  Takes all sorts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing by yourself, you can use [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin to publish your artifacts to local maven repository(you don't have to install maven for this) and on your dependent project you can simply say use mavenLocal repository for dependencies.

If you are on a company, I suggest installing a repository manager and deploy your artifacts to this repository so others can use. You can use their respective plugins to deploy easily. ([Gradle Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin), [Gradle Nexus Plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin), these are just deployment plugins, you have to setup respository manager to. There are other repository management tools also.) Doing the above process from CI server is the preferred way.

To use latest version of a dependency, you can use [Gradle Versions Plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin). If the versioning happen often, using snapshot versions also a possibility.